# SAS - Macro variable within % statements

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a SAS file that I maintain on a monthly basis. I often automate parts of the code with macro variables such as:

```
%let currMth = 201511;
```

But I am having problems using the macro variables within other macro statements. How do I do this?

```
%inc 'C:\FolderPath\&currMth.\filename.xlsx';
```

Doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I just needed to use double quotation marks.